# PDFkit in rails3 always generate a PDF without styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdfkit

I am trying to generate a PDF using PDFKit .After added".pdf" after url,it worked and get a PDF page but it always look like a default page with only text content.I can't style the PDF pages.

I have this line in "views\layouts\application.html.erb"

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
```

and in "assets\stylesheets\application.css",I have

```
@media print {
body{
    font-size:40px;}

#container{
    background:black;
    padding:20px;
    font-size:200%;
    }
}
```

but it didn't work. The pdf page is still like default style.

Could u guys give me a hand with this?
THX

Comment: Would you not consider using `wickedpdf` - https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf you might actually find what you want to do much easier food for thought.

Comment: Thanks Djj. I have tried wicked_pdf before. But it seems a  little tricky to me.Could u plz tell me how to add a link for printing current page into a PDF in a show.html?

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup PDFKit to use print media styles?

```
config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware", :print_media_type => true
```

Comment: THX Leito, but I already have this line in"config\application.rb"  PS:I am on win OS